# Why does "... >> out | sort -n -o out" not actually run sort?

Tags: bash, find, cut

As an exercise, I should find all .c files starting from my home directory, count the lines of each file and store the sorted output in sorted_statistics.txt, using find, wc, cut ad sort.
I found this command to work

```
find /home/user/ -type f -name "*.c" 2> /dev/null -exec wc -l {} \; | cut -f 1 -d " " | sort -n -o sorted_statistics.txt
```

but I can't understand why

```
find /home/user/ -type f -name "*.c" 2> /dev/null -exec wc -l {} \; | cut -f 1 -d " " >> sorted_statistics.txt | sort -n sorted_statistics.txt
```

stops just before the **sort** command. 
Just out of curiosity, why is that?

Comment: It doesn't "stop just before" anything. All parts of a pipeline run at the same time -- the last part is run at the same time as the first. (Though if you redirect output of a prior component so it doesn't actually feed anything into a later one, then that later pipeline component has very little to do).

Comment: ...that said, having two different parts of a pipeline write to the same output file doesn't make much sense. It might help to describe what you're doing in more detail (and perhaps assert whether the append behavior is desired -- do you *really* want to merge multiple sets of statistics into the same output file, so you have both the numbers for an old version of `foo.c` and *also* the numbers from a new one?)

Comment: I think I've got it. I'm new to piping in general, and I thought of it as sequential execution, that's why I thought the second version would have worked just fine. Thanks for your explanations!

Answer (score 1):

This part of the command makes no sense:

```
cut -f 1 -d " " >> sorted_statistics.txt | sort ...
```

because the output of **cut** is appended to the file *sorted_statistics.txt* and no output at all goes to the **sort** command. You will probably want to use **tee**:

```
cut -f 1 -d " " | tee -a sorted_statistics.txt | sort ...
```

The **tee** command sends its input to a file and also to the standard output. It is like a Tee junction in a pipeline.

Comment: What's the benefit of the `cat` here? If you want to append, `tee -a` can do that in-line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: if you use the operator  `>>`, I suppose you want to append content to the file *sorted_statistics.txt*. **tee** can't do that, as far as I know. If you want to overwrite *sorted_statistics.txt*, obviously, you don't need the **cat** nor the *tail_sorted_statistics.txt* file.

Comment: As I said, `tee` *can* do an append, if given the `-a` argument. `tee -a somefile` appends content from its stdin to the end of `somefile`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I am happy to hear that. Did you edit your answer after I read it, or was I blind?

Comment: I edited the first comment before you posted your response; perhaps the update wasn't pushed in time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Anyway, I corrected my answer above. Thanks for this information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160017/discussion-between-pierre-francois-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: I'm new to linux in general, didn't know about the tee command. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You were appending everything to sorted_statistics.txt ( consuming all the output ) and then trying to use that none existing output in a pipe for sort. I have corrected your code so it works now.

```
find /home/user/ -type f -name "*.c" 2> /dev/null -exec wc -l {} \; | cut -f 1 -d " " >> tmp.txt && sort -n tmp.txt > sorted_statistics.txt
```

Regards!

Comment: Why use `tmp.txt` at all? GNU `sort` can take care of writing to temporary files on disk itself behind-the-scenes if there's not enough RAM to store state in-memory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I dont know. Ask OP, I modified as less as possible so its clear for OP what was not working.

Comment: Given as the OP doesn't know what they're doing, it's probably better to go for best-practices as a target, vs smallest-possible-change.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for a similar but correct solution. I actually have a working command, I was just wondering why the other isn't